# Is QTUM is a coin or a Token?

Tags: blockchain, tokens, etherscan, protocol, mainnet

According to Etherscan Qtum is a Token, holding supply with verified smart contract. But its official site contains its own protocol and integration mechanism. Is it still a token under ETH or it has been moved out as Coin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QTUM is a now a separate blockchain.

Similarly to other projects like EOS and Tron they used Ethereum to lauch their ICO. And afterward they lauched a separate blockchain.